# How can I use crontab in Linux to run a command from 9am til 1pm and update every 2 minutes?

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to keep some metrics so I want crontab to run on Wednesdays from 9am to 1pm and update every 2 minutes, but I don't want my text file to be overwritten, just appended. I'm really stuck on how to do this.

I will be using the command

```
df -h >> metricFile
```

I think the >> metricFile part will append the file instead of overwriting if I'm not mistaken.

so metricFile is appended every 2 minutes from that time frame on Wednesdays.
Using the typical crontab format below:

```
minute hour day month weekday command
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Headline doesnt match question. I answered the headline then readjusted when I noticed the question mentions Wednesday

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down the bits:

- Every 2 minutes: */2
- 9am - 1pm: 9-13
- Any day: *
- Any month: *
- Wednesdays: 3

Here's the command:

```
*/2 9-13 * * 3 ~/myscript.sh
```

Where `myscript.sh` contains:

```
/bin/df -h >> /tmp/metricFile.txt
```

Note I changed `metricFile` to `/tmp/metricFile.txt`. Absolute paths are better than relative.

I recommend the cron run a script e.g. `~/myscript.sh`. This is because you are unsure of the command. That way you can perfect your script independent if cron. Changes to the script will not require editing the crontab. From what I can tell your syntax looks fine. However cron jobs may run:

- from a different directory
- as a different user
- with different environment variables

Adding debugging lines to your script such as:

```
whoami > /tmp/whoami.txt
pwd > /tmp/pwd.txt
env > /tmp/env.txt
```

can be helpful in troubleshooting.